# Citation: How To Cite a Book in ACM Style With Multiple Cities?

Tags: citation-style

I need to cite from the "[Gang of Four](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Design_Patterns)" book, but the title page has fourteen cities listed. I have found information about APA and MLA styles regarding this, but how do I cite a book with multiple cities in ACM style? The [ACM Reference Format](https://www.acm.org/publications/authors/reference-formatting) does not have such an example.

Comment: Would the downvoter care to comment on what can be changed in my question? I've attempted at length to find the answer online to no avail.

Comment: Usually a book only has one city as the _publication_ venue. Perhaps with more recent ones with all the online culture there could be multiple cities, but with a book this old I think it should not be the case. I couldn't see the title page listing 14 cities in your link, but could it be a possibility that the 14 cities are not the publication venue?

Comment: @justhalf how can I determine the publication venue, then? I don't see that in the book. The title page lists the publisher, and beneath that the list of fourteen cities. https://www.amazon.com/Design-Patterns-Elements-Reusable-Object-Oriented/dp/0201633612